# Перехват нажатия кнопок

Tags: windows, права, windows-7, браузер

Всем доброго времени суток!

Разрабатываем новостной портал.

По периметру территории будут расположены компьютеры с Windows 7.

На каждом будет открыт браузер с нашим порталом и введены ограничения на  права пользователя ([ссылка](http://hippocat73.livejournal.com/74203.html)).

Кнопкой F11 браузер будет переведен в full-формат. Но как реализовать запрет на выход из full-формата? Ведь если выйдем из full-формата, то можно и закрыть браузер, что категорически нежелательно!

Answer (score 1):

Тогда уж вам придется заблокировать и кнопки альт таб, и виндовс, и альт ф4, и еще, наверное, какие-то. Это, конечно, все можно сделать, но, может, нужно рыть в сторону запрета выхода из полного режима. Самый простой вариант - сломать кнопку ф11 (ну а если в программном смысле, это можно делать с помощью виндовс хукков), но лучше не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/  - вот хорошее решение. Выбираем кнопку, отключаем её, пишем в реестр, перезалогиниваемся, и всё. =)